# How to popup url in lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, popupwindow

I am trying to popup the url using the lightbox, when i click the button, the lightbox call has been made, but the given url is not pop-up in the light box.

when i click the button it is showing popup with just small white screen

here is code i have used

code:

```
<a class="example-image-link" href="uitab/index.html" data-lightbox="example-1"><input class="buton" type="button" value="View details" name="View details"></a>&nbsp;</td>
```

how can i solve this?

Comment: I'm not sure lightbox plugin has support to open a webpage in a frame, might need to check other plugin

Answer (score 1):

try to use something like that may be it helps

```
<a class="various fancybox.ajax" href="uitab/index.html">Ajax</a>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".various").fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 800,
        maxHeight   : 600,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '70%',
        height      : '70%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none'
    });
});
```

and read the example url here

```
http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/
```